# Column sums of $A$ from column sums of $A A^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix. Is it possible to infer anything about the column sums of $A$ by precisely knowing the column sums of $A A^T$? What if we impose some restriction on the $A $ that we choose? The nice thing would be to exactly know what the column sums are, but I have already numerically checked that this is impossible. Specifically, I can construct a random positive definite matrix, take its Cholesky factorization $L$, then take a random orthogonal matrix $Q$. $L$ and $LQ$ will have different column sums even though $L L^T=(LQ) (LQ)^T$.

Some context: I'm dealing with an SDE $dX=b(X) dt + \sigma(X) dW$. It is really only defined up to distribution (so its diffusion matrix $a$ is known but the matrix $\sigma$ can be any solution to $\sigma \sigma^T=a$). I'm trying to see if there is any way to simplify the differential of $\sum_i X_i$. The fluctuation term in this differential looks like $\sum_{i,j} \sigma_{ij} dW_j$. That can be rewritten as $\sum_j dW_j \sum_i \sigma_{ij}$, which exposes the role of the column sums of $\sigma$ in my problem.

Comment: Indeed ,Drift and diffusion of the SDE are unknown ?

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki The drift is exactly known. The diffusion matrix $a$ is known but the matrix $\sigma$ that appears in the equation is not specified by my model (so I am more or less free to choose it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the column sums of $A$ are precisely the entries of $A^Tx$, where $x$ is the vector of $1$s.

On the other hand, the column sums of $AA^T$ are simply the entries of $AA^Tx$.  We can therefore calculate
$$
A^Tx = A^{-1}(AA^Tx)
$$
Or at least, you could if you had a formula for $A^{-1}$. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: My apologies: the question was changed slightly to talk about column sums. I think the obvious changes to your idea might go through anyway, but still, it would be good to run through them.

Comment: Actually $A^T x$ gives the row sums of $A^T$, which are the column sums of $A$ ...

Comment: @HM two wrongs make a right, then?

Comment: I think this is about all that can be done, so thanks!